# How to plot non integer values in r

Tags: r, plot

I do have a dataset that contains temperatures "TEMP2" (which are not integers) and precipitation types "pcp_type" (qualitative data):

```
   stn               time1 TEMP2 pcp_type
11 SIO 1981-01-02 09:00:00   0.7     snow
12 SIO 1981-01-02 12:00:00   1.5     snow
15 SIO 1981-01-02 21:00:00   0.4     snow
22 SIO 1981-01-03 18:00:00   3.8     rain
23 SIO 1981-01-03 21:00:00   3.7     rain
24 SIO 1981-01-04 00:00:00   5.3     rain
```

I've been trying to search for an answer (and sorry if it already exist I swear I didn't find it) on how to plot non-integer values (temperatures) so that I can see what type of precipitation (pcp_type) is related to each temperature.

I did try a bwplot but I do have issues with the scale for temperatures as I guess it doesn't match because of the non-integer thing OR because it's cumulative...(I'm a newbie).

What would be the best plot type for this kind of data that you would advise to use? (as I want to keep non rounded values for temperatures).

```
bwplot(FINAL_SYNOP2$pcp_type~FINAL_SYNOP2$TEMP2)
```

Comment: I'd recommend a dot plot. Something like `ggplot(FINAL_SYNOP2, aes(x = TEMP2, y = pcp_type, color = pcp_type) + geom_point()`.

Comment: Though overall, I think this isn't a great question for Stack Overflow - "what would be the best plot type" is more opinion-based than objective, which isn't on-topic here as it tends to generate more of a discussion than an answer.

Comment: I understand your point and I'm sorry if it looks like I was starting an open discussion. In reality, as I'm a total beginner I have no idea of which plot works for non integer values (as I tried bwplot and it didn't work out so well). I'll try your solution, thanks a lot!